# If $m$ is even, and $n$ is odd, does $2(m+n)+2$ have to be divisible by $4?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

[image]

Can anybody give me an idea of how to solve this? I can't seem to find a counterexample because every integer I choose for m and n is divisible by 4.

Comment: Hint:  they used the same $k$ twice.  In particular, as the proof would have it, $n=2k+1=m+1$.  But the "theorem" was meant to hold for all pairs $(m,n)$.

Comment: The proof is incorrect for $m=10$ and $n=3$. For with $m=10$, $k=5$, and with $n=3$, $k=1$, not the same. Minor imperfection in the proof, easily fixable. You will not find a counterexample to the theorem, the assertion is true.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, those values evaluate to 28, which is divisible by 4.

Comment: The point is that there is a flaw in the **proof**. There is no $k$ such that *simultaneously* $10=2k$ and $3=2k+1$. That's a counterexample to an assertion in the "proof." But the theorem is true, the little error in the proposed proof can be fixed.  There is no counterexample to the assertion of the theorem.

Comment: That is a really weird text book.  I'm wondering if the proof was supposed to be something like 2(m+n) + 2 is neve divisible by 8 or something, but that's too obscure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is flawed, but the theorem is in fact correct, so you won’t be able to find a counterexample to it.

The error in the proof is using $k$ in the expansions of both $m$ and $n$, thereby making $n=m+1$. The correct argument is that there are integers $k$ and $\ell$ such that $m=2k$ and $n=2\ell+1$, so that

$$\begin{align*}
2(m+n)+2&=2\big(2k+(2\ell+1)\big)+2\\
&=4k+2(2\ell+1)+2\\
&=4k+4\ell+2+2\\
&=4(k+\ell+1)\;,
\end{align*}$$

which is indeed a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Oh, perfect! I didn't think of that. Is this sufficient as a counterexample or is there a value for k that makes the proof false?

Comment: @Nic: The problem is simply incorrectly stated: there is no counterexample. The ‘proof’ is even correct as far as it goes; the problem is that it shows only that $2(m+n)+2$ is a multiple of $4$ when $m$ is even and $n=m+1$, so any other example, like $m=2$ and $n=5$, is not covered by the proof. It’s not a counterexample to the theorem, which is actually true, or to the ‘proof’, which is correct for the $m$ and $n$ values to which it applies, but it is an instance of the theorem that is not covered by the ‘proof’.

Comment: @fleablood: There are no counterexamples. $2\cdot11+2=24=4\cdot6$.

Comment: Of course.  I had a brain fart.  The false proof shows m+n = 4k + 1 so I got in the mind set that it was trying to use that m+n was one more than a multiple of 4, so I got it in my mind that the false theorem was that 2(m + n) + 2 was *never* a multiple of 4.  A brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that assuming m is even and thus equal to 2k for some k,  and that in assuming that n is odd and thus equal to 2k + 1 for some k, that these are the same value when they need not be.

This leads to some false assumptions.  For example: n and m are consecutive, which of course they don't need to be.  Or that m + n = 2k + 2k + 1 = 4k + 1, is 1 more than a multiple of 4.  Neither of these need to be true.

*BUT* then this gets weird.  The proof that 2(m+n) + 2 is divisible by 4 *is* a true result.  We *can't* do 2(m + n) + 2 = 2(4k + 1) + 2.  But we *can* (and *must* do 2(m + n) + 2 = 2(2k + 2j + 1) + 2 = 4(k+j) + 2 + 2 = 4(k+j) + 4= 4(k+j + 1).

So 2(m+n) +2 *is* always divisible by 4.

However, this would be a *better* example of a false application leads to untrue theorem:

Prove 2(m + n) + 2; m even and n odd is never divisible by 8.

Proof:

m = 2k

n = 2k + 1

so 2(m + n) + 2 = 2(4k + 1) + 2 = 8k + 4 and is not divisible by 8.

This is of course not true.

m = 2k

n = 2j + 1

so 2(m + n) + 2 = 2(2(j + k) +1) + 2 = 4(j+k) + 4 which *will* be divisible by 8 if (j + k) is odd.

Example:  if m = 4 = 2*2 and n = 7 = 2*3 + 1 so 2(4 + 7) + 2 = 24 = 3*8.

Comment: That is not a counterexample: that’s an instance of the theorem. $24$ is a multiple of $4$.